# Trouble solving for exponents with constants

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, constants

so I have this equation I need to solve for $i$, where $k$ and $u$ are arbitrary constants:
$$
u^{{\frac1{k^i}}} = k
$$
And these are the steps I've accomplished so far (all logs are in base 2):
$$
log(u^{{\frac1{k^i}}}) = log(k)
$$
$$
\frac1{k^i} \cdot log(u) = log(k)
$$
$$
log(u) = log(k)\cdot k^i
$$

But now I'm stuck... how do I solve for $i$ from here? I'm forgetting how I would do this. Any help and explanation of how log and exponent math would be great! (Also please correct me if what I've done so far is wrong.) I also hope my math formatting makes sense, thank you!

Comment: i don't understand what exactly do you mean?

Comment: instead of having the first equation = _k_, I would like it to = _i_. In otherwords, I'm trying to solve for _i_.

Comment: $\log u = \log k*k^i$ so $k^i = \frac {\log u}{\log k}$ so $i = \log_k(\frac {\log u}{\log k})$.  That's $i$.  That's all there is.  You *are* allowed to express logs of logs, you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
u^{(1/k)^i} = k
$$
taking logs as you have done works 
$$
\frac{1}{k^i}\log u = \log k
$$
then we have
$$
\frac{1}{k^i} = \frac{\log k}{\log u}
$$
Taking logs again
$$
-i\log k = \log \left(\frac{\log k}{\log u}\right)
$$
so 
$$
i = \frac{1}{\log k}\log \left(\frac{\log u}{\log k}\right)
$$

or take logs on your final statement
$$
\log (\log u) = \log (\log k) + i \log k
$$
we used 
$$
\log(ab) = \log a + \log b\\
\log(a^n) = n\log a
$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a base 2 logarithm you could use base $k$, since it is implicitly non-negative.
$$
log_k\left(u^{{1/k}^i}\right) = log_k(k)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{k^i} log_k(u) = 1
$$
$$
log_k(u) = k^i
$$
Apply $log_k$ one more time, and you're done.
$$
log_k(log_k(u)) = i
$$